# Need help scraping page with button "load more" calling AJAX to load more items

Tags: python, ajax, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am using the following code:

```
from logging import exception
from selenium import webdriver 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from time import sleep
import datetime
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import random
import pandas as pd
from Scrapingtools import joinfiles
from Scrapingtools import uploadfiles


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
#options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
# options.add_argument("start-maximized")
# options.add_argument("window-size=1900,1080")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"/usr/bin/chromedriver", options=options)

#url = 'https://www.pccomponentes.com/procesadores'

url_list = [
     'https://www.pccomponentes.com/procesadores',
    #  'https://www.pccomponentes.com/discos-duros/500-gb/conexiones-m-2/disco-ssd/internos',
    #  'https://www.pccomponentes.com/discos-duros/1-tb/conexiones-m-2/disco-ssd/internos',
    #  'https://www.pccomponentes.com/placas-base/amd-b550/atx',
    #  'https://www.pccomponentes.com/placas-base/amd-x570/atx',
    #  'https://www.pccomponentes.com/tarjetas-graficas',
    #  'https://www.pccomponentes.com/memorias-ram/16-gb/kit-2x8gb',
    #  'https://www.pccomponentes.com/ventiladores-cpu/socket-amd-am4',
    #  'https://www.pccomponentes.com/ventiladores-suplementarios/120x120',
    #  'https://www.pccomponentes.com/fuentes-alimentacion/750w/fuente-modular',
    #  'https://www.pccomponentes.com/cajas-pc/antec/atx/be-quiet/cooler-master/corsair/deepcool/fractal/lian-li/msi/phanteks/silverstone/tacens/tempest'
     ]

df_list =[] 
store = 'PCComponentes'
extraction_date = datetime.datetime.today().replace(microsecond=0)

page_source = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'lxml')
    # print(soup)
    items = soup.find_all('div',class_='col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4')
    # print(len(items))
    print('Found' ,len(items), 'items in', url)    

    for item in items:

            product_name = item.find('h3',class_ = 'c-product-card__title').text.strip()
            try:
                price = item.find('div', class_ = 'c-product-card__prices-actual cy-product-price-normal').text[:-1]
            except AttributeError:
                price = item.find('div', class_ = 'c-product-card__prices-actual c-product-card__prices-actual--discount cy-product-price-discount').text[:-1]
            try:
                old_price = item.find('div',class_ = 'c-product-card__prices-pvp cy-product-price-normal').text[:-1]
            except AttributeError:
                old_price = "No discount"
            # try:
            #     availability = item.find('div', class_ = 'c-product-card__availability disponibilidad-inmediata cy-product-availability-date').text.strip()
            # except AttributeError:
            #     availability = item.find('div', class_ = 'c-product-card__availability disponibilidad-moderada cy-product-availability-date').text.strip()  
            # except AttributeError:
            #     availability = "No Date"  
            try:
                rating = item.find('span',class_ = 'c-star-rating__text cy-product-text').text.strip()
            except AttributeError:
                rating = ""
            try:
                reviews = item.find('span',class_ = 'c-star-rating__text cy-product-rating-result').text.strip()
            except AttributeError:
                reviews = ""
            try:
                brand = item.find('article')['data-brand'] 
            except AttributeError:
                brand = "No brand"
            try:
                category = item.find('article')['data-category']
            except AttributeError:
                category = "No category"
                   
            #  print(product_name, price, old_price, rating, reviews, brand, category, store, extraction_date)

            product_info =  {
                'product_name' : product_name,
                'price' : price,
                'old_price' : old_price,
              # 'availability' : availability,
                'rating' : rating,
                'reviews' : reviews,
                'brand' : brand,
                'category' : category,
                'store' : store,
                'date_extraction' : extraction_date,
            }
            df_list.append(product_info)
            
sleep(random.uniform(3.5, 7.5))

df = pd.DataFrame(df_list)
print(df)
```

It is very similar to other which works fine. The problem in this page is that the bottom make an ajax call and I don´t know how to handle.

The bottom seems to work but no new item appears in the page, and the script only retrieve de first 24 items when in turn there would be over one hundred.  In this case, the browser opens

In fact it seems that the bottom enter in a loop showing "ver mas" and "cargando" text alternative.

I thought it could be a problem with the load page, but testing with different time waiting doesn´t work.

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do things like this is probably:

```
driver.execute_script('''
  setInterval(() => document.querySelector('#btnMore').click(), 1000)
''')
sleep(100)
```

You don't have to worry about catching anything, it will quietly fail if it's not there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but It doesn´t work, the bottom flashes intermittently between "ver mas" and "cargando" but not new data appears and the script returns only the first 24 items.

Comment: and could you retrieve all the products from the page?, not only the first 24 but all of them?

Comment: so I am testing following methods

    ``wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#btnMore'))).click()``
    and
   `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="btnMore"]'))).click()` but none of them working,  no new products appears and only return the first 24 items