# Requests returns 403 error but page works with direct link in a browser

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I came from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67892097/need-help-scraping-page-with-button-load-more-calling-ajax-to-load-more-items).

I have tried a different approach, with my little knowledge I realized that the button is calling an specific web page.

Suppose we navigate [this](https://www.pccomponentes.com/procesadores) page, when you click in "Ver más" button it seems that call [this](https://www.pccomponentes.com/listado/ajax?page=2&order=relevance&gtmTitle=Procesadores%20PC&idFamilies%5B%5D=4) URL so I think we can **scrape** this page and iterate through a number of pages collecting this way all the products in these pages.

Ok, then my new code looks like this

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import datetime
from time import sleep
import random
from Scrapingtools import joinfiles
from Scrapingtools import uploadfiles

#url = 'https://www.pccomponentes.com/procesadores?page='

url_list = [
     'https://www.pccomponentes.com/listado/ajax?page=3&order=relevance&gtmTitle=Procesadores%20PC&idFamilies%5B%5D=4',
    'https://www.pccomponentes.com/listado/ajax?page=1&order=relevance&gtmTitle=Placas%20Base&idFamilies%5B%5D=3'
    ]


df_list =[] 
store = 'PCComponentes'
extraction_date = datetime.datetime.today().replace(microsecond=0)

for url in url_list:

    for x in range(0,1):
        headers = ({'user-agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36"})
        r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
      # r = requests.get(url + str(x), headers = headers)
        # print (url + str(x))
        print()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser')
        # print(soup)
        items = soup.find_all('div',class_='col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4')
        print('Response:'+str(r.status_code)+'.Found '+str(len(items))+' items in '+url + str(x))
        
        for item in items:

            product_name = item.find('h3',class_ = 'c-product-card__title').text.strip()
            try:
                price = item.find('div', class_ = 'c-product-card__prices-actual cy-product-price-normal').text[:-1]
            except AttributeError:
                price = item.find('div', class_ = 'c-product-card__prices-actual c-product-card__prices-actual--discount cy-product-price-discount').text[:-1]
            try:
                old_price = item.find('div',class_ = 'c-product-card__prices-pvp cy-product-price-normal').text[:-1]
            except AttributeError:
                old_price = "No discount"
            # try:
            #     availability = item.find('div', class_ = 'c-product-card__availability disponibilidad-inmediata cy-product-availability-date').text.strip()
            # except AttributeError:
            #     availability = item.find('div', class_ = 'c-product-card__availability disponibilidad-moderada cy-product-availability-date').text.strip()  
            # except AttributeError:
            #     availability = "No Date"  
            try:
                rating = item.find('span',class_ = 'c-star-rating__text cy-product-text').text.strip()
            except AttributeError:
                rating = ""
            try:
                reviews = item.find('span',class_ = 'c-star-rating__text cy-product-rating-result').text.strip()
            except AttributeError:
                reviews = ""
            try:
                brand = item.find('article')['data-brand'] 
            except AttributeError:
                brand = "No brand"
            try:
                category = item.find('article')['data-category']
            except AttributeError:
                category = "No category"
                   
            #  print(product_name, price, old_price, rating, reviews, brand, category, store, extraction_date)

            product_info =  {
                'product_name' : product_name,
                'price' : price,
                'old_price' : old_price,
              # 'availability' : availability,
                'rating' : rating,
                'reviews' : reviews,
                'brand' : brand,
                'category' : category,
                'store' : store,
                'date_extraction' : extraction_date,
            }
            df_list.append(product_info)
            
    sleep(random.uniform(3.5, 7.5))

df = pd.DataFrame(df_list)
#print(df)
```

At this point, I have two blocks that prevent me from following development. First, and most important is the 403 error.

Trying someting like this

```
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.76 Safari/537.36'} # This is chrome, you can set whatever browser you like
response = requests.get('https://www.pccomponentes.com/listado/ajax?page=3&order=relevance&gtmTitle=Procesadores%20PC&idFamilies%5B%5D=4', headers=headers)

print (response.status_code)
print (response.url)
```

doesn´t work at all. I have changed the user-agent but nothing works :(.

if you copy this link and paste in a browser the page returns products which I think I could get with the code paste above.

The second is the iteration but first need help with the request made to the page.

Any idea about how can I resolved.

pd: Sorry for the length of the post I want to put in context of why I trying to achieve.

Regards

Comment: This is likely because the site realises you are trying to scrape it and so prevents that from happening by forbidding you. Some good ways around this are to set the user agent to imitate another browser or use a headless library for making the requests.

Comment: user agent doesn't works and I don't known why.